# error: request for member "machine" in something not a structure or union

Tags: pointers, struct

When I'm trying to compile below program I'm getting error as request for member "machine" in something not a structure or union

```
struct machine
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
struct config
{
    struct machine *machine;
    int n;
};
int main()
{
    struct config *conf;
    struct machine *mach;

    mach->a=1;
    mach->b=2;
    mach->c=3;

    conf.machine=mach; /* error in this line */  

return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this bug.. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: With `struct config *conf;` you just define a pointer from type `config conf` but you have to allocate memory for it. And the same for `struct machine`. Use malloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conf` is a pointer, not a structure, so you have to dereference it, just like you did with `mach`.

```
conf->machine = mach;
```

Also, you need to allocate memory for both `conf` and `mach`.